# Do I need to delete the branch after it gets merged in the "main" branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, pull-request, git-pull

We are using Github for our project. The original owner of the project is making commits directly to the "main" branch, while I have created a branch named "freelancer/kamal" and I am making commits to it.

The problem I am facing is that I am not sure whether I should delete my branch after my code gets merged or I should continue working on it.

For example, I fix three small CSS issues and I push the code and open pull request, then the owner merges this PR to the "main" branch.

After that, I need to work on other issues in this project.

But I am confused that should I delete the branch that is already merged or should I continue working on my branch i.e. "freelancer/kamal"?

Comment: Mostly a matter of preference, be sure to discuss your workflow with the project owner, but both ways work (creating new branches for each feature or reusing the same branch name each time).

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks for clarifying. 

I have one more question that is related to this: how do I continue my work when a branch still needs to be merged? For example, I fixed some issues and I pushed the branch. But it may take some time for the other person to merge the branch (let's say 4 hours due to the time difference). But I can't stop work for 4 hours, I need something to get done. How should I work in that situation?